# Multiple if/elif statements in a Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I'm new to Python and one concept that's taken some getting used to is the list comprehension. I've read that they can improve computation speed when used correctly and that they're something to know well if you're to learn Python the right way.

I'm writing a program that implements a particle aggregation algorithm that involves the accumulation of up to 10^6 particles to a growing cluster. I'm going back through my code to optimize performance anywhere possible, and I have the following function:

```
 def step_all_walkers(walkers): 
    updated_positions = []
    for walker in walkers: 
        decision = random.randint(1,4)
        if decision == 1: 
            updated_walker = (min(walker[0]+1, N-1), walker[1])
        elif decision == 2: 
            updated_walker = (max(walker[0]-1, 1), walker[1])
        elif decision == 3: 
            updated_walker = (walker[0], min(walker[1] + 1, N-1))
        elif decision == 4: 
            updated_walker = (walker[0], max(walker[1]-1, 1))

        updated_positions.append(updated_walker)

    return updated_positions
```

This function makes every particle (or walker, as I call them in the code) take a step of unit length in a random direction, and prevents the particles from walking off an N x N grid. I notice that I am creating and returning a new list `updated_positions`, and since this list and the input `walker` list are potentially very large, what I sort of know about list comprehensions tells me this might be a good time to use one. However, in some other posts on this question where there is only one if/else to be evaluated, people responded by saying just use a good ole fashion for loop.

I have a few questions then:

1) Can multiple if/elif statements be done in a list comprehension?

2) Does it make sense to write this for loop as a list comprehension? Are there any advantages to doing so?

My main purpose for asking this question is to build up more intuition for when a list comprehension is appropriate, and also to see if this function can be made more efficient with one.

Comment: 1. Multiple if-**expressions** can be chained but this will look ugly in my opinion. 2. A list comprehension also creates a new list. So you would win neither clarity nor much efficiency here.

Comment: A list comprehension also makes a new list, so I don't think there is much to gain there.  I would not be concerned about even a few lists of 10^6 integers/tuples of integers for memory size.  Your code above is pretty clear.  If you wanted to try a list comprehension, you could make a "move" function that covers the cases and returns a new position and call that function within the list comprehension, but I don't think you'll get any performance boost.

Comment: You could use a dictionary of functions to pick the update function and then you could write the list comprehension as follow: `return [update_map[randint(1,4)](walker) for walker in walkers]`

Answer (score 1):

I would turn that into a lookup dictionary to start with and then you might be able to consider a list comprehension

```
decisions = {1: lambda walker: (min(walker[0]+1, N-1), walker[1])}
return [decisions[random.randint(1,4)](walker) for walker in walkers]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the OP's questions.

Comment: @Georgy - I'd partially agree, the first question asks if multiple if else can be done in a list comprehension - yes, but there isn't any need to and it wouldnt be very readable anyway. The second question is partially opinion based and partially too small of an example to discuss advantages

Answer (score 0):

A case where [list comprehensions should not be used](https://hashnode.com/post/when-should-you-not-use-list-comprehensions-in-python-cj2a35qsh0020u9532z9e1n6z) is when the logic in too complex.

For loops are simpler then since they allow:

- Including comments to explain the code.
- Use of control flow keywords like continue.
- Debug of sections of the more easily using logging statements or asserts.
- Allow others to easily see the complexity of the logic by scanning down the lines

However, as Sayse suggests, we can often simplify the logic with additional data structures and helper functions to allow list comprehension.

**List comprehension with no if/else statements** (need for logic bypassed)

```
def step_all_walkers(walkers, N):
  def decision(walker):
    " Helper function for making a decisions "
    # Place decision choices into a data structure
    options = [
      lambda walker: (min(walker[0]+1, N-1), walker[1]),
      lambda walker: (max(walker[0]-1, 1), walker[1]),
      lambda walker: (walker[0], min(walker[1] + 1, N-1)),
      lambda walker: (walker[0], max(walker[1]-1, 1))]

    while True:
      n = random.randint(0, 3)  # use rather than (1, 4) to 
                                # provide proper index into options
      yield options[n](walker)

# Now, list comprehension is straight forward to follow
return [decision(walker) for walker in walkers]
```